# Android: getWriteableDatabase() error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception, getwritabledatabase

I have been having this problem for a few days now, and really cant see a problem in the code, so a few extra eyes to have a look is really appreciated.

I start the app by simply creating a new database manager object, and opening the managers database.

```
 DBManager db_manager = new DBManager(this);
 db_manager.open()
```

App should then perform a simple insert transaction, but an error is thrown:

```
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961):     at com.test.DB.DBManager$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DBManager.java:44)
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961):     at com.test.DB.DBManager.open(DBManager.java:61)
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961):     at com.test.DB.Display.onCreate(Display.java:26)
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
02-11 18:13:30.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
```

The DatabaseHelper class:

```
    class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){            
            the_db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
}
```

The DBManager methods, open() is causing the problem.

```
    public DBManager(Context c){
    this.context = c;
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
}


// Makes the_db available to the Manager class.
public DBManager open() throws SQLException{
    the_db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){            
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
```

You already get the database in your `onCreate()` method, is the SQLiteDatabase parameter **db** and you must use it.

**EDIT :**
You get the `NullPointerException` because you call `executeSQL()` on `the_db` which is a field in `DBManager`, probably declared like:

```
SQLiteDatabase the_db;
```

or

```
SQliteDatabase the_db = null;
```

so when you actually get in the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` you call `executeSQL()` on null. The code for `DBManager` should be something like this:

```
public class DBManager {

    //the actual database you will use to insert,select etc after the getWritableDatabase() call
    private SQLiteDatabase the_db; 
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper helper;

    public DBManager(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Makes the_db available to the Manager class.
    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        the_db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "something.db", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // the db is the SQLiteDatabase that android will offer you
            // and you must use it!
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE nametables(name TEXT);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The onCreate() does is unable to be overridden.

Comment: @MindDrip Maybe my answer was confusing, i'm referring to the `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){            
            the_db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
` from your `DatabaseHelper` (which extends SQLiteOpenHelper), method that CAN be overriden -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: hmm strange, eclipse gives me a "Override is disallowed for this location" error.

Comment: @MindDrip I don't know what are you doing but the `DatabaseHelper` class should be something like this: class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){            
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { }
}

Comment: Ok, my brain is melting due to the time spent fixing this bug. I had already overridden that method, and had tried to do so to the e constructor. So, the @Override was in my code already.

Comment: @MindDrip So everything is ok now?

Comment: No, this is not the cause of the error. I really cannot spot what it is as it seems to be correct with the examples that are online.